# Return Shared Element Transition after ImageView changes

Tags: android, animation, imageview, fragment, shared-element-transition

I have a fully working shared element transition between 2 fragments, lets say A to B, and they both share an ImageView. Everything works out except when I replace the shared ImageView on B. Currently I'm changing it using the following code:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(getArguments().getString(Constants.APPVIEW_FEATURE_IMAGE_URL)).asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        if (getView() != null) {
                            ((ImageView) getView().findViewWithTag(Constants.TAG_FGRAPHIC)).setImageBitmap(resource);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I replace the ImageView that I received from A on B with a higher definition one, since this is a header Image that will extend from a listView to a full width header.

The problem is that when returning from B to A, the animation goes wrong because when I press Back, the image changes size right away to it's size on A instead of using the animation scaling down from it's B size to A size. It still moves from the header to the A location correctly, it's just the size problem.

If I don't replace the image, no problem happens and everything goes normal.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it with Glide, but this is how I did it with Picasso.

```
             Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(AppController.getInstance().getThumbor().buildImage(url)
                            .resize(widthPlaceholder, heightPlaceholder)
                            .fitIn()
                            .toUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.color.light_gray)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .noFade()
                    .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .into(target);

            Target target = new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(AppController.getInstance().getThumbor().buildImage(url)
                                    .resize(width, height)
                                    .fitIn()
                                    .toUrl())
                            .placeholder(d)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .noFade()
                            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                            .into(imageView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(AppController.getInstance().getThumbor().buildImage(url)
                                    .resize(width, height)
                                    .fitIn()
                                    .toUrl())
                            .placeholder(R.color.light_gray)
                            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .noFade()
                            .into(imageView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(AppController.getInstance().getThumbor().buildImage(url)
                                    .resize(width, height)
                                    .fitIn()
                                    .toUrl())
                            .placeholder(placeHolderDrawable)
                            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .noFade()
                            .into(imageView);
                }
            };
```

I am loading lower resolution picture and I am putting it as placeholder (background image), and than triggering higher res picture loading.

Comment: (I'm not using picasso on my project so I didn't test your code but I'm not using Glide library to change the image, just using the ImageView native methods (tried both setImageDrawable() and setImageBitmap()) and it doesn't work either, so I doubt that would make it work. Probably have to change some ImageView setting or add something not regular to the transition

Comment: Try after pressing back and before calling super.onBackPressed to set smaller image inside ImageView.

Comment: Did the onBackPressed suggestion but It didn't work. Although it initially started to come right for some brief ms, then alot of weird things happen (image goes to middle of screen very fast, then main fragment animations start (there should be no animation here), then the image jumps again to her final place). Not sure what else to do :/

Comment: I am out of ideas. I had same problem, and I remember that it worked much better with Picasso for some reason.

Comment: So it was a bug on the emulators, on the real device it worked properly. So many hours wasted because of this... Thanks for the help anyway =)

Comment: Be careful with that. Maybe it's working good just on some devices.